# Inkscape: un-stretch distorted text

Tags: inkscape

I am importing a figure with multiple text objects in inkscape (e.g. graph). I sometimes need to change the overall width of the figure to match publishers requirements (e.g. single column figure cannot be over 8 cm wide). Therefore, I select everything and scale the width. This leaves text distorted, but I need to maintain the text aspect ratio. How can I now un-stretch the text afterwards to not look distorted?

The only way I found so far, was to select each text object, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the XML editor, find the `scale` attribute of the distorted node and remove it. However, this is

1. cumbersome (have to do it on all text nodes manually) and
2. moves the text object around.

Comment: This issue also came up in [this inkscape forum post](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=32153). Your method is still the best way.

Comment: For common cases it's usually quicker to undo the resize, deselect text, redo resize, and reposition text at new locations.

Answer (score 1):

This answer come 4 years after the original question because I found a sneaky workaround
that I didn't see posted anywhere else.  [image: restore distorted text]

You might have to play around with the z-order of the text objects to get the positions right.

Answer (score -1):

#### Resize [scale] all selected text in place, by a set %

1. Select text elements
2. Open Transform window, select Object drop-down > Transform... [Shift + Ctrl + M]
3. Open the Scale tab
4. Set a percentage to resize down by
5. Tick *Scale proportionally* and *Apply to each object separately*
6. Press Apply

Comment: Not answering the question: it's not resetting the aspect ratio of the text.